# Find nearest range for a time that does not overlap existing ranges

Tags: r, datetime, data.table

I have a `data.table` 'd1', with a date-time variable, 'fdate':

```
d1 = data.table(fdate = as.POSIXct("2007-06-23 23:54:54"))
```

I have another `data.table` 'd2', with two date-time variables, 'start' and 'stop':

```
d2 = data.table(start = as.POSIXct(c("2007-06-23 00:00:00",  "2007-06-24 00:00:00")),
                stop = as.POSIXct(c("2007-06-23 07:00:00", "2007-06-24 07:00:00")))
#         start                stop
# 1: 2007-06-23 2007-06-23 07:00:00
# 2: 2007-06-24 2007-06-24 07:00:00 # The range closest to "2007-06-23 23:54:54"
```

I know how to use `foverlaps` function to find overlapping ranges, i.e. where 'fdate' is between 'start' and 'stop'. The question is how can I find the nearest range for an 'fdate' that is not contained in any start/stop range?

In the example, 'fdate' should be linked to the range in row 2. This is because fdate is +24hrs after range 1, but only 4 min before range 2.

What's the most efficient way to perform this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using rolling join:

```
mDT <- melt(d2[, rn := .I], id.vars="rn")
d1[, rownum := 
    mDT[.SD, on=.(value=fdate), roll="nearest", rn]]
```

Comment: IIUC, the OP wants to *find the nearest range for an 'fdate' that is **not** contained in any start/stop range*. This answer will find the nearest end point even if located *inside* a range, e.g., `"2007-06-23 06:54:54"`.

Comment: @Uwe I am assuming that OP knows how to use foverlaps to find those with overlaps and hence those without overlaps as well. If I am mistaken, I will add this part as well to create d1.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, define the distance between `fdate` and each date range as the absolute distance between `fdate` and either `start` or `end`, whichever is shorter, and find the date range with the smallest distance from `fdate`.

```
fdate = as.POSIXct("2007-06-23 23:54:54")
start1 = as.POSIXct("2007-06-23 00:00:00")
stop1 = as.POSIXct("2007-06-23 07:00:00")
start2 = as.POSIXct("2007-06-24 00:00:00")
stop2 = as.POSIXct("2007-06-24 07:00:00")

which.min(c(min(abs(fdate - start1), abs(fdate - stop1)), 
            min(abs(fdate - start2), abs(fdate - start2))))

[1] 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP has requested to

> find the nearest range for an `fdate` that is not contained in any
> `start`/`stop` range

There are two possible interpretations in case `fdate` *is*  contained in a range:

- Find the next nearest *different* range, or
- return `NA`.

The approach below can be used to get answers for both interpretations.

#### Find the next nearest *different* range

1. Add row numbers to `d2` because it is the required information
2. Do a backward rolling join to find the nearest range `start` which is later or equal to each `fdate`, calculate the time difference
3. Do a forward rolling join to find the nearest range `stop` which is earlier or equal to each `fdate`, calculate the time difference
4. `rbind()` both subsets so that there are two rows for each `fdate`
5. For each `fdate` pick the range which has the least time difference or the smaller row number in case of a tie
6. order the result by `fdate`

which is implemented as

```
d2[, rn2 := .I]
result <- rbind(
  d2[d1, on = .(start = fdate), roll = -Inf, 
     .(rn2 = x.rn2, fdate = i.fdate, delta = x.start - i.fdate)],
  d2[d1, on = .(stop = fdate),  roll = +Inf, 
     .(rn2 = x.rn2, fdate = i.fdate, delta = i.fdate - x.stop)]
)[order(rn2), .(rn2 = rn2[which.min(delta)]), keyby = fdate]

result 

                 fdate rn2
1: 2007-06-22 23:00:00   1
2: 2007-06-23 06:00:00   2
3: 2007-06-23 08:00:00   1
4: 2007-06-23 15:30:00   1
5: 2007-06-23 23:00:00   2
6: 2007-06-24 06:00:00   1
7: 2007-06-24 08:00:00   2
```

Note that the use case has been expanded to test various configurations with `fdate` outside, inside, and in between the two ranges (see *Data* section).

The result is easier to verify when visualized:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(result) +
  aes(x = fdate, y = factor(rn2), label = seq.int(nrow(d1)), colour = factor(rn2)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(nudge_y = 0.1) +
  geom_segment(aes(yend = rn2, x = start, xend = stop, label = NULL), data = d2, size = 2) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  ylab("matching d2 row number")
```

[image]

- Points 1, 3, 5, and 7 are not contained in any range and have been assigned to the respective nearest ranges 1 or 2.
- Point 4 is not contained in any range but is located exactly in the middle between `stop` of range 1 and `start` of range 2 causing a tie in the distance. In case of a tie, `order(rn2)` ensures that the lower range is picked predictably.
- Point 2 is contained in range 1 and is assigned to the next *different* range 2.
- Point 6 is contained in range 2 and is assigned to the next *different* range 1.

#### Or, return `NA`

For the second interpretation, `NA` is assigned to those `fdate` which are contained in a range. To identify those cases, `data.table`'s `%inrange%` operator is used which is easier to use than `foverlaps()`:

```
result[fdate %inrange% d2[, .(start, stop)], rn2 := NA_integer_][]
```

> ```
>                  fdate rn2
> 1: 2007-06-22 23:00:00   1
> 2: 2007-06-23 06:00:00  NA
> 3: 2007-06-23 08:00:00   1
> 4: 2007-06-23 15:30:00   1
> 5: 2007-06-23 23:00:00   2
> 6: 2007-06-24 06:00:00  NA
> 7: 2007-06-24 08:00:00   2
> ```

The plot

[image]

shows that points 2 and 6 are no longer assigned to any range.

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
d1 <- data.table(fdate = as.POSIXct(c("2007-06-22 23:00:00", 
                                      "2007-06-23 06:00:00",
                                      "2007-06-23 08:00:00",
                                      "2007-06-23 15:30:00",
                                      "2007-06-23 23:00:00",
                                      "2007-06-24 06:00:00", 
                                      "2007-06-24 08:00:00")))
d2 <- data.table(start = as.POSIXct(c("2007-06-23 00:00:00", "2007-06-24 00:00:00")),
                 stop  = as.POSIXct(c("2007-06-23 07:00:00", "2007-06-24 07:00:00")))
```